# How do I remove a member from all roles that match a regex?

Tags: node.js, regex, discord, discord.js

How do I remove a member from all roles (the role names) that match a regex? I'm new to discord.js and I don't know that much JavaScript, so any help would be appreciated.

I'm creating a bot that enables users to change their colour so I want the command to remove all their existing colour roles before adding the new one.

The regex is `/^#[0-9a-zA-Z]{6}$/`, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, seeing as you already have the regex you're halfway there. A way I would approach this is to get the member's roles and filter the ones that match the regex. Then I'd simple call the `removeRoles` method on the user to remove all the roles.

Below you can find some sample code, try it and let me know how it goes.

```js
client.on("message", async message =>
{
  // Get the user
  let member = message.member;

  // Get all the roles which match the regex
  let filteredRoles = member.roles.filter((role) => /^#[0-9a-zA-Z]{6}$/.test(role.name));

  // Remove the roles from the member
  member.removeRoles(filteredRoles);
});
```